# Problem retrieving data using jQuery AJAX request with PHP proxy

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, proxy

I'm interviewing for a company and they've given me a take home assignment that I have unlimited time to complete. One of the specifications is that I use a PHP API proxy to get around CORS for their API. I'm not permitted to use any PHP or JS libraries for this, aside from JQuery. I'm very new to PHP and am used to fetching data with React, so I feel a little out of my element. I've found what looks to me like it should be a solution here:

https://github.com/joseftw/php-rest-proxy

...but I can't get it to work. Whenever I load the page and check the console, it just stays `<empty string>` for both GET and POST requests (on Firefox). I know the calls are firing because they do perform `console.log('test')` if I add that. So then where's the data?

Here's the code for my PHP proxy file:

```
    <?php

  $url = $_REQUEST["url"];

  if(!$url) {
    echo "You need to pass in a target URL.";
    return;
  }

  $response = "";
  switch (getMethod()) {
    case 'POST':
      $response = makePostRequest(getPostData(), $url);
      break;
    case 'GET':
      $response = makeGetRequest($url);
      break;
    default:
      echo "This proxy only supports POST AND GET REQUESTS.";
      return;
  }

  echo $response;

  function getMethod() {
    return $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; 
  }

  function getPostData() {
    return http_build_query($_POST);
  }

  function makePostRequest($data, $url) {
    $httpHeader = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
    
    return makePutOrPostCurl('POST', $data, true, $httpHeader, $url);
  }

  function makeGetRequest($url) {
    $ch = initCurl($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
  }

  function makePutOrPostCurl($type, $data, $returnTransfer, $httpHeader, $url) {

    $ch = initCurl($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $type);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $returnTransfer);
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
  }

  function initCurl($url) {
    $httpHeader = array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36');

    return $ch;
  }


?>
```

And here are my AJAX requests in my script.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'proxy.php?url=https://reqres.in/api/users',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { name: 'Zlatan Ibrahimovic' },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });

    $.get('proxy.php?url=https://reqres.in/api/users', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The endpoint I've provided is from a sample API and not the company's API. Still, I can't get the proxy/AJAX combo to work with anything. This is day 2 of this and I'm spinning my wheels. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Am I totally off-base with the PHP proxy setup, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get this to work. PHP:

```
<?php

// getting the baseURL from the request
$baseURL = $_REQUEST['url'];

// getting the request method sent in to the proxy
function getRequestMethod() {
  return $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; 
}

// getting the POST data from a POST request
function getPostData() {
  return http_build_query($_POST);
}


function makeGetRequest($baseURL) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $fullURL = $baseURL.<URLparams here>; 

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullURL);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  
    if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
        echo $e;
    } else {
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    return print_r($json);
    }
}

function makePostRequest($baseURL) {
    $ch = curl_init();
  $data = http_build_query($_POST);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

    if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
        echo $e;
    } else {
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    return print_r($json);
    }
}

$response = "";
switch (getRequestMethod()) {
  case 'GET':
    $response = makeGetRequest($baseURL);
    break;
  case 'POST':
    $response = makePostRequest($baseURL);
    break;
  default:
    echo "There has been an error";
    return;
}

echo $response;
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'proxy.php?url=<Endpoint here>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            partnerName: 'applicant',
            partnerPassword: 'd7c3119c6cdab02d68d9',
            partnerUserID: 'expensifytest@mailinator.com',
            partnerUserSecret: 'hire_me',
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
    $.get(
        'proxy.php?url=<Endpoint here>',
        function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JS script inside script body. And Once I get the response I send It back to the dom using document.getElementById('result') --- See inside html body; And When i try with /users I get nothing interesting even if there's a result on that link to. I think the link you're trying to reach is /user. I've added an isset verification for the url. Otherwise it breaks when you don't add the ?url inside the navigator url.

```
<?php
$url = null;

if (isset($_REQUEST["url"])) {
    $url = $_REQUEST["url"];
}

if(!$url) {
    echo "You need to pass in a target URL.";
    return;
}

$response = "";

switch (getMethod()) {
    case 'POST':
        $response = makePostRequest(getPostData(), $url);
        break;
    case 'GET':
        $response = makeGetRequest($url);
        break;
    default:
        echo "This proxy only supports POST AND GET REQUESTS.";
        return;
}

echo $response;

function getMethod() {
    return $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
}

function getPostData() {
    return http_build_query($_POST);
}

function makePostRequest($data, $url) {
    $httpHeader = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));

    return makePutOrPostCurl('POST', $data, true, $httpHeader, $url);
}

function makeGetRequest($url) {
    $ch = initCurl($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($response);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

function makePutOrPostCurl($type, $data, $returnTransfer, $httpHeader, $url) {

    $ch = initCurl($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $type);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $returnTransfer);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}

function initCurl($url) {
    $httpHeader = array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36');

    return $ch;
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="module">
    addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        console.log('ok');
        const xhtml = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhtml.onreadystatechange = (res) => {
            if ((res.target.status === 201 || res.target.status === 200) && res.target.readyState === 4) {
                console.log('----------------res object--------------------' + "<::::>");
                console.log(res, "res");

                console.log('----------------status--------------------' + "<::::>");
                console.log(res.target.status);

                console.log('------------------readyState------------------' + "<::::>");
                console.log(res.target.readyState);

                console.log('------------------response------------------' + "<::::>");
                console.log(res.target.response);

                console.log('------------------responseText------------------' + "<::::>");
                console.log(res.target.responseText);
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = res.target.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhtml.open('POST', 'https://reqres.in/api/user');

        xhtml.send(JSON.stringify({
            url: 'proxy.php?url=https://reqres.in/api/user',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {name: 'Zlatan Ibrahimovic'},
        }));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to use the provided url replace from this line ...xhtml.open('POST', 'https://reqres.in/api/user');

```
       const url = JSON.parse(`<?php echo $url?>`);
        xhtml.open('POST', url);

        xhtml.send(JSON.stringify({
            url: 'proxy.php?url=' + url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {name: 'Zlatan Ibrahimovic'},
        }));
```

Comment: Why in xhtml.open() are you doing a GET request, but in xhtml.send() a POST? It seems as if these requests aren't actually going through the proxy like this...when I comment out everything in xhtml.send(), I get the same results as when it's uncommented.

Sorry for my ignorance, I'm not used to doing things this way and am trying to wrap my head around what's actually going on.

Comment: My mistake, It works because the app accepts both methods. Use POST for both please it works too :)

Comment: You could also  use the given url like so... check my older message.

Comment: If you want to use a post method then you need to use a form and set the method to post and no action. With a submit button inside the form. use onclick method. Add all the script inside a function but the function must stay in the script block. And call the function when clicked like so onclick="myFunction()";